# Why does this "trick" work to figure out the order of a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $g \in S_{11}$ the symmetric group on $11$ elements. Suppose we take some element $g=(1,3,2,4)(5,11)(7,9,10)$ if we want to compute the order of $g$ then we simply take the lowest common multiple of each of the cycle lengths.

So here it would be $o(g)=12$ the lowest common multiple of $4,2$ and $3$.

Also why is the subgroup generated by a set $X$ (say) denoted $\langle X \rangle$ always equal to the finite products of the elements of $X$ and there inverses?

Is that just by the properties of groups/subgroups (like closure under composition and closure under inverses)?

If anyone could explain why the trick works and comment on my second question to clear things up I would appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Are you comfortable with the idea that $|\langle g \rangle| = o(g)$, or does that fact need explaining too?

Comment: In the title you mention the order of a group, but in the body of the question you only talk about the order of an element. While the two are related, which one exactly is your question about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $g$ as a function $g:\{1,2,\dots,11\} \to \{1,2,\dots,11\}$, such that $g(1) = 3$, $g(3) = 2$, and so on.  The identity permutation is given by $e(i) = i$ for all $i$, and the order of $g$ is the lowest positive $n$ for which $g^n(i) = i$.

Note that for $i \in \{1,3,2,4\}$, we will have $g^n(i) = i$ if and only if $i$ is a multiple of $4$.  Similarly, $g^n(i) = i$ for $i \in \{5,11\}$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $2$.  $g^n(i) = i$ for $i \in \{7,9,10\}$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

All together, we will have $g^n(i) = i$ for *every* $i$ in $\{1,2,\dots,11\}$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $2,3,$ and $4$.  The lowest such positive $n$ is, by definition, the least common multiple of $2$,$3$, and $4$.

---

For your second question: by the definition of a group generated by $X$, $\langle X \rangle$ must at least contain all finite products of elements from $X$ and their inverses.  The more interesting part is that no other elements are required in order to make $\langle X \rangle$ into a group, as can be proven with careful treatment of definitions.

Comment: Very well explained thank you. I voted this as best answer.